# Radion button onclick delay beahaviour

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, onclick, radio-button

I have a list of radio buttons,

And i have function that runs on radio button click event
here is my jQuery

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function () {
        var str = $(this).attr("class");
        if (str == undefined) {
            str = "";
        }
        if (str.search("selectedRadio") < 0) {
            $("input[type='radio']").removeAttr("class").attr('checked', false);
            $(this).attr('checked', true).attr("class", "selectedRadio");
            id = $(this).attr('id');
            MID= $("input[type='hidden'][name='HiddenMedID']").val();
            ID = $(this).val();
            PID = $("#GetNewPatientID").val();
                $(this).parent().prepend("<img src='/icon_loading.gif' id = 'fetchingSP' width='18' height='18' id='PleaseWaitRadioCircle' />");
                FunctionOne();
                FunctionTwo(ID, PID, MID);
                FunctionThree(ID, PID);
                FunctionFour(ID, PID);
        }
    });​
```

**I noticed that, when i have the below function in the click event**
there is a delay in radio button click. I mean if user clicks on radio button it will take a second or half to select that radio button.

```
 FunctionOne();
 FunctionTwo(ID, PID, MID);
 FunctionThree(ID, PID);
 FunctionFour(ID, PID);
```

I don't understand how is this related, if i remove  or comment these four function in the click event than there is no delay.

**This is ASP.Net MVC3.0 Application on razor views.**

Comment: Those functions must be doing significant work.  If you wrap the functions in `setTimeout(function() { -- functions here -- }, 1)` the radio button may be updated faster.